# Infinite limit of finitary functors

Tags: category-theory, functors

I'm learning about finitary functors. I have two conflicting results:

1. $F_A X = X^A$ is finitary iff $A$ is finite. Therefore, $X^\mathbb{N}$ is not finitary.
2. $F X = X$ is finitary and the category of finitary functors has small limits (it is a presheaves category). Therefore, $X^\mathbb{N}$ is finitary, because it is the small limit of finitary functors (the product diagram over $\mathbb{N}$ as a discrete category).

What's happening?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functor $X \mapsto X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not the product of $\mathbb{N}$ copies of the functor $X \mapsto X$ in the category of finitary functors $\text{Set} \to \text{Set}$ (it can't be since this functor is not finitary). This product exists but it is something else: namely, thinking of $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ as the set of functions $\mathbb{N} \to X$, it's the set of functions $\mathbb{N} \to X$ which only take finitely many values. (Hence the inclusion of finitary functors into all functors doesn't preserve infinite limits.)

Here are some reasons you might have been confused:

- Given a finitary functor $F : \text{Set} \to \text{Set}$, you can restrict it to a functor $\text{FinSet} \to \text{Set}$, and this produces an equivalence of categories between the functor category $[\text{FinSet}, \text{Set}]$ and the category of finitary functors.
- Also, limits in this functor category exist and are computed pointwise, and so the product of $\mathbb{N}$ copies of the functor $X \mapsto X$, viewed as a functor $\text{FinSet} \to \text{Set}$, is in fact $X \mapsto X^{\mathbb{N}}$.

But! The corresponding finitary functor $\text{Set} \to \text{Set}$ is computed by taking a filtered colimit over all finite subsets of $X$ (which it necessarily must be in order for the result to be finitary), and if you compute that filtered colimit you get the functor above on $\text{Set}$, not $X \mapsto X^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that given a small category $\mathcal{C}$, the category of finitary functors is *not* a presheaf category, but rather a full subcategory of the functor category $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$. It follows rather easily from the fact that filtered colimits commute with finite limits in $\mathbf{Set}$ that this subcategory is closed under *finite* limits in $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$, but there is no reason for this to extend to *small* limits.

Comment: I am confused, isn't the category of finitary functors (on $\mathbf{Set}$) $\left[\mathbf{Fin},\mathbf{Set}\right]$? Isn't that a presheafs category for $\mathbf{Fin}^\mathrm{op}$?

Comment: I thought you meant this : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finitary+functor Did you mean something else?

Comment: I think it is equivalent? In the answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390738/is-the-category-of-finitary-mathsfset-endofunctors-cartesian-closed) they talk about the equivalence?

Comment: Mmh, I think you're right. I suspect that the problem is that the equivalence is not just given by restriction to finite sets, and that while the category of finitary functors has small limits, they don't necessary correspond to "pointwise" limits. But I'd need to check to be sure (or wait for someone who's more qualified than me to chime in).

Comment: I've accepted @qiaochu-yuan's answer, although your comments were right, thanks!